# Weird first element when converting vector<vector<string>> to map<string, string> c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I am trying to convert a vector like that could look like this: `[["foo=bar+1", "foo=foo/2", "foo=foo-foo"]]`, into a map like this `{"foo": "bar+1", "foo": "foo/2", "foo": "foo-foo"}`. So far I have this code:

```
string currentBankSetting;
for (int i = 0; i < bankContenseVector.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bankContenseVector[i].size(); j++) {
        currentBankSetting = bankContenseVector[i][j];
        vector<string> keyValue = fixCSGNUtils.split(currentBankSetting, "=");
        scriptVars.insert(pair<string, string>(keyValue[0], keyValue[1])); 
    }
}

// This is just to read out scriptVars
for (auto it = scriptVars.cbegin(); it != scriptVars.cend(); ++it) {
    cout << (*it).first << ": " << (*it).second << endl;
}
```

The bank contense vector in this case is: `[["ef=e-fz", "ei=nf*pt", "go=og+le"]]`. The output is odd. It's:

```
: map...? <- This element
ef: e-fz
ei: nf*pt
go: og+le
```

So my question is: How did the first element in the dictionary come to be and how can I stop from happening? I don't want to remove it as it does not look very nice (I know)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what is going wrong without knowing what fixCSGNUtils.split() is doing. It's also tough to know whether there is actually an extra entry in the map or if the first entry is just formatted weird or if this just a feature of the editor you are using.

Regardless, below is a working example with most of your code intact and/or replaced with standard library functions. This will output as follows:

ef: e-fz
ei: nf*pt
go: og+le

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, string> mp;
    vector<vector<string>> a;
    vector<string> b = {"ef=e-fz", "ei=nf*pt", "go=og+le"};
    a.push_back(b);

    string c;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++) {
            c = a[i][j];
            size_t pos = c.find("=");
            string key = c.substr(0, pos);
            string remainder = c.substr(pos+1, c.length());
            mp.insert(pair<string, string>(key, remainder));
        }
    }

    for (auto it = mp.cbegin(); it != mp.cend(); ++it) {
        cout << (*it).first << ": " << (*it).second << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```